# Java: read a stream of byte from a socket

Tags: java, sockets, byte

Im setting up a software that send a message in byte [] and receive a stream of byte.
Example, send the array

```
byte[] replayStatuse = new byte[] { 0x55, (byte) 0xAA, 0x0B, 0x00, 0x0A, 
0x1C, 0x03, 0x41, 0x01, 0x00 }
```

and I receive something similar. I did the test using PacketSender and I can see the answer in Hex when I ask the status.
Im using

```
InputStream socketInputStream = socket.getInputStream();
```

I already tried the various method I found here on stack and other forum but it didnt works.
Methods like this:

```
int read;
while((read = socketInputStream.read(buffer)) != -1)
{
   String output = new String(buffer, 0, read);
   System.out.print(output);
   System.out.flush();
}
```

I tried to use int read of type char, byte or other format but nothing. In my console it prints strange char (U)

Im using:

```
InputStream socketInputStream = socket.getInputStream();
socketInputStream.read();
```

Im expecting to get a byte[] and be able to read with the function:

```
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(byteArray));
```

So I can then handle the various cases and transform if need to a String or HEX
Thank you all

Comment: What exactly is the problem? It's not clear to me what you want to do or what the problem is. You are already reading the bytes in the buffer which is a byte array.

Comment: Why are you creating a `String` from the bytes you've read from the socket?

Comment: You need to explain what you are trying to do here.  Your code for reading the byte array appears to be correct.  The problem is what you do with the array of bytes after you have read it.  You code appears to be rendering it to text, but it is not clear if you intend to do that, or what you are actually trying to achieve.  The latter will determine *how* you should be rendering the array.

Comment: @ILightWas The main problem is how to read the data that the board send back to me. I don't even know which is the ending char in order to stop the while! -1 isnt working!
My goal is to have in the console a human readable string OR put the answer into an array of byte and then after the while be able to print it out with "System.out.println(Arrays.toString(byteArray));"

Comment: @JamesKPolk Im creating a String so I can read it on the console and I can manipulate easily, but I can also use the byte array.

Comment: @StephenC You re right. I want to store the byte I received into an array of bytes and be able to exit from the while cycle. THe final scope of my problem should be a FIFO stack that send message and wait for answer, if a command will have an aswer the program wait for it, then execute it, then go for the next one! But first I need to fully get the message that the board sent me back!

Answer (score 0):

The character 'U' is not strange, it is the ASCII character for the hexadecimal value of 0x55 (i.e. the same as your first value in the test array).  The next few values in the array may be throwing off the print statement.  I recommend checking/displaying the length of 'buffer' so you know how many bytes were placed into the array.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understand your problem completely but lets try

From the beginning you have a source of bytes, I will assume the size is unknown.

```
byte[] buffer = new byte[4096]; //I assume you have something like this

//Lets use this to accumulate all the bytes from the inputstream
ByteArrayOutputStream byteStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

int read;
while((read = socketInputStream.read(buffer)) != -1)
{
    byteStream.write(buffer, 0, read); //accumulates all bytes
}

byteStream.flush(); //writes out any buffered byte

byte[] allBytesRead = byteStream.toByteArray(); //All the bytes read in an array
```

This is all the bytes that were sent. Say you want to print each byte in hex

```
for(byte b : allBytesRead) {
    //might not be a good ideia if its something big. 
    //build a string with a StringBuilder instead.
    System.out.println(String.format("%02X", b));
}
```

Now it's up to you how you will process these bytes.

Comment: Thank your reply help me a lot!
My question wasnt so clear but your help me a lot and I figured out the solution!
When I tried to print out I didnt convert my output so the console show me random stuff!
Also my packet has a byte that contain the length of the message so using that and a For cycle I read the hwole message without using a While!!!!
THANK AGAIN